# Deserializing each line of binary file C#

Tags: c#, loops, stream, deserialization

I'm serializing objects to a .txt file from a GUI.

```
private void ReserveTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        Reservation CreateReservation = new Reservation(textBoxFirstName.Text, textBoxSecondName.Text, dateTimePickerDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), comboBoxTable.Text, 5, textBoxPhoneNumber.Text);           
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(Globals.filepath,FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, CreateReservation);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

After that I want to deserialize those Objects to a table. But I don't know how to get each object from each line, I'm desirializing currently only the first Object of the .txt file. I've tried to extract the data I wanted and it worked for the first line of the .txt file.

Is it possible to loop thorugh each line of the .txt file and extract the data of each Object? Or is there any better way to do this? I need to get each attribute of each object to display it in a table.

Thanks in advance.

```
     private void ShowReservation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream(Globals.filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Reservation ReadReservation = (Reservation)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(ReadReservation.Firstname);
        Console.WriteLine(ReadReservation.Lastname);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is not useful for text files. And binary files do not have "lines".

Comment: "*I'm serializing objects to a .txt file from a GUI.*" Why don't you use JSON? BinaryFormatter is deprecated.

Comment: This is a project for university, it was given to use xml or .txt. Txt. seemed easier to me.

Comment: @KlausGütter What else would you suggest to do this?

Comment: You might consider Poul Bak's suggestion to use JSON. Or - if the data is really simple, maybe CSV.

Comment: @KlausGütter Okay so I would switch to JSON - could you give me Code snippets on how to serialize and deserialize?

Comment: Use a textwriter or something, Microsoft gives examples in their documentation. Make a loop. Use Linq, whatever. This is basic programming  which you should learn from a course or book. Stack overflow is not an on demand tutorial site